# Using variable controller name in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm writing a helper in CodeIgniter that I need to reuse in several controllers.  The initial data loaded in the view rendered by the helper can vary depending on which controller uses the helper.

I'm trying this:

```
    $controller = $CI->router->fetch_class();
    $init = $CI->$controller->get_initial_data($id);
```

but getting

```
    Call to a member function get_initial_data() on a non-object
```

When I view the variable contents with:

```
    print_r($controller);
```

I see the name of the correct controller.  Problem seems to be with $CI->$controller.   Any ideas on how I can use the variable as the controller reference?

Comment: You're trying to access the methods of a *controller*? You can't do that outside of the controller itself. So, if I understand correctly, you want the helper to call the `get_initial_data` method of the controller that called it? You can't actually do that. Why not have the controller call its own `get_initial_data` method and send the result as a parameter to the helper function?

Comment: Thanks.  Carl Markham suggestion didn't work but this did.  Thanks for the fast response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access controller methods from anywhere else but from inside the controller itself.  So, there is no way for the helper to call the `get_initial_data` method.

What you want to do is have the controller call its own `get_initial_data` method and pass the result as a parameter to the helper function.

For example (in your controller):

```
$data = $this->get_initial_data($id);
my_helper_function($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`$CI->{$controller}->get_initial_data($id);`